# How to find the number of marbles which someone has when it is a multiple of an unknown number?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, arithmetic, recreational-mathematics, number-systems, cryptarithm

The problem is as follows:

> Mark has $\overline{ab}$ marbles and Ferdinand has $\overline{cde}$
> marbles. Find the total of marbles which both have knowing that the
> product of the number of marbles they have is the ninth part of
> $\overline{abcde}$.

The alternatives in my book are as follows:

$\begin{array}{ll}
1.&\textrm{237 marbles}\\
2.&\textrm{133 marbles}\\
3.&\textrm{126 marbles}\\
4.&\textrm{128 marbles}\\
5.&\textrm{132 marbles}\\
\end{array}$

How exactly are these numbers being asked found?. What I've attempted to do was to write the question into an equation.

Since it mentions that the product between the numbers is:

$$\overline{ab} \times \overline{cde}= \frac{1}{9} \overline{abcde}$$

And they ask to find $E=\overline{ab}+\overline{cde}$

This is assuming that the intended number system is on **base 10**.

But that's it. There's where I'm stuck. The only other thing which I could spot was that $c$
cannot be zero as well $a$. But from there I don't know how to use the hint which they have referring to being the ninth part of $\overline{abcde}$ does it exist some sort of identity or thing which to use to use this clue?.

Since I am lost into this question, can someone explain this in a **step by step approach and the most detailed as possible** to find the answer?. The part most confusing to me was to reduce the available options within the numbers to get the right combination to match what it is being asked.

More importantly, **does it exist an approach to get the answer by finding individually first the digits involved** instead of getting the requested answer first?.

Comment: They have $14$ and $112$ marbles, total $126$. Indeed $14\times112=1568=1/9\,14112$

Comment: @Raffaele I noticed that you mentioned to use Mathematica as a brute force method to find the numbers, but this question was intended to be solved without relying on computer aid. But perhaps does it exist a more intuitive way to solve this?.

Comment: The answer given by Joshua Wang is neat

Comment: @Raffaele The approach which I *intended to ask* was some which relied less in algebra and more into an intuitive way some like going trial and error digit by digit as how it is done in cryptaritm. I'm not contesting the way how it was solved. I mentioned that the starting point of his method was not very obvious and relied more into factorization.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\overline{ab} = x$ and $\overline{cde} = y$. Then, we want to find $x + y$ given $xy = \frac{1000x + y}{9}$. We have:

$$9xy = 1000x + y$$

$$9xy - 1000x - y = 0$$

$$81xy - 9000x - 9y = 0$$

$$81xy - 9000x - 9y + 1000 = 1000$$

$$(9x - 1)(9y - 1000) = 1000$$

Now, since $9x-1$ and $9y-1$ are integers, we can find factor pairs of $1000$ and solve for $x$ and $y$. (Keep in mind here that $x < 100$ and $y < 1000$.) We find:

$$(9x - 1)(9y -1000) = 125(8)$$

$$9x -1 = 125, 9y - 1000 = 8$$

$$9x = 126, 9y = 1008$$

$$x = 14, y = 112$$

$$x + y = \boxed{126}$$

An alternate, shorter solution (that may not work with different answer choices):

Note that $\overline{abcde}\equiv a + b + c + d +e\equiv 0\pmod{9}$ because we are working in base $10$. Then, $\overline{ab} + \overline{cde} = 10a + b + 100c + 10d + e \equiv a + b + c + d+e \equiv 0\pmod{9}$. Thus, the correct answer must be divisible by $9$. Note that the only answer choice divisible by $9$ is $126$, so this must be the correct answer.

Comment: $1$ has one digit and can't be the solution. You can set $9x-1=125;\; 9y-1000=8$ to get the actual solution: $14+112=126$.

Comment: Thank you, I wasn't thinking all that much when I got to that part of the solution.

Comment: Never mind: I got the solution with brute force using *Mathematica* :)

Comment: @JoshuaWang Your method uses factorization and trial and error once the algebraic equation is made to match the appropiate factors for $1000$. The approach I was intending to ask was more driven by *cryptarithm*, does it exist a way to use this method and not relying much in algebra?

Comment: @JoshuaWang First I must say that it was not very obvious to say $xy=\frac{1000x+y}{9}$, but I noticed that this comes from $\overline{ab}\times 1000= ab000$ hence $ab000+cde=abcde$ and you used this as a starting material to developing your method. I had to re-read your answer and it took me time to also notice that you constrained the values of $x<100$ and $y<1000$ are because of the definition $\overline{cde}=y$ then $y<1000$.

Comment: @JoshuaWang But *why* did you had multiplied by $9$ and added $1000$ to both sides of the equation? Was this done on purpose?. What were you intending to build and **why**?. This part I dont understand from your strategy. More importantly *why*?. When we get to the equation, we get to the point that all is left is just trial, but how many trials have you attempted to get to the factors $8$ and $125$?.

Comment: @JoshuaWang The only way which I think it could help was to get the $\textrm{factors(1000)}=2^3\cdot 5^3$ and luckily these $8$ and $125$ match to get the answer. But it could had been $4$ and $250$ however in this case neither $4$ or $250$ added to $1$ give multiples of $9$ maybe *was this the rationale which have you used?.* Again I believe you should include a clarification stating why did you used $xy=\frac{1000x+y}{9}$. Can you do that please?.

Comment: I have edited my answer to include a more elegant approach. To answer your earlier question, that approach for reducing an integer equation to factored form is called "Simon's Favorite Factoring Trick", and involves a method similar to completing the square.

Comment: @JoshuaWang I'm sorry for being slow at catching up. But interesting! I didn't knew the name of the identity which you have just referenced. Since I'm not very familiar with the use of modular arithmetic. I am *stuck with* how did you come up with the multiple of 9 for the sum of both, please read the following comment.

Comment: @JoshuaWang How did you come up with $\overline{ab}+\overline{cde}=10a+b+100c+10d+e\equiv a+b+c+d+e\equiv 0 (\mod 9)$. The part which confuses me is **why** $10a+b+100c+10d\equiv a+b+c+d+e$. I mean if you add the two digit number with a three digit number **how can you be so sure that the result will be also divisible by $9$** Can you include a clarification for this please? By the way I had the impression that you used a method similar to completing the square, but I didn't know it had a name, does it exist other *methods like that list to check up*?. Can you attend my earlier doubts please?

Comment: Because it is equivalent to the sum of the digits of the two digit number, plus the sum of the digits of the three digit number, or the sum of the digits of the five digit number, modulo 9. This is an interesting property that stems from $10^{n} = 99...999 + 1\equiv 1\pmod{9}$.

Comment: @JoshuaWang Yes I know that property. I'm just not yet getting it. It remains unanswered **we don't know the result of the sum of the two digit number plus the three digit number** we do know the sum of all their digits and those numbers put together make a number which is divisible by $9$ (referring to $\overline{abcde}$.

Comment: @JoshuaWang The thing is, only if we do prove that the sum of the digits of two digit number plus the sum of the the digits of the three digit number **equals** to the sum of the digits of the five digit number and those digits are equal to $\overline{abcde}$ then we can start looking up in the choices to which is divisible by $9$. That's where I'm stuck. **How do you prove it**?. Should I understand by reading at your equation that $10a\equiv a$ hence $10a=a$ and $100c\equiv c$ and $10d\equiv d$ and $10d=d$? Is this part correct in my understanding?. **Can you please help me with this part?**